# canvas pinch and zoom with initial scale less than 1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one outer canvas inside which I am loading another canvas (large size). I have set the clip geometry so only a part of inner (large) canvas is visible on screen.

Since the inner canvas is large in size so I have kept the initial scale of inner canvas as 0.4 i.e. I have applied composite transform on inner canvas and made scaleX and scaleY as 0.4.

Now I have implemented gesture listener methods OnPinchStart and OnPinchDelta. In OnPinchDelta I am zooming the canvas.

The problem is that since the initial scale is 0.4 so until the scale reaches (or scale crosses 1), the canvas is not zooming from center means it's position gets changed. However as soon as scale factor reaches (or crosses) 1, the zooming of canvas starts properly.

In short when the scale factor is less than 1 the zooming is not happening from center or other way, canvas position does not remain proper.

I have tried many different approaches but scale factor less than 1 is not working properly for me. Any help.

Comment: Why don't you multiply Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top with the HorizontalChange in the PinchDelta?

Comment: you mean to say Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop methods ?

Comment: I'll include a more detailed explanation in an answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
var factor = // calculate this based on amount of data and the speed
var width = // element rendered width
var height = // element rendered height
var changeInWidth = (1-factor) * width; // can be 0, neg or pos
var changeInHeight = (1-factor) * height;
var changeInX = changeInWidth / 2;
var changeInY = changeInHeight / 2;

Canvas.SetLeft(element, Canvas.GetLeft(element) + changeInX);
Canvas.SetTop(element, Canvas.GetTop(element) + changeInY);
```

Just make sure your element is wrapped by a Canvas, otherwise the Left and Top would be ignored.

In order to calculate factor, you can use e.DistanceRatio;
It can be used itself as factor, but you can multiply it by a constant if you want to increase(e.g. 1.2) or decrease (0.8) the speed of zooming.

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me how to calculate factor (inside pinch delta event) and also what do you mean by "Just make sure your element is wrapped by a Canvas", I have inner canvas which is put on one outer canvas.

Comment: Regarding canvas, your structure is OK. I added more comments about factor. Also this link can be useful: http://alvaropeon.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/implementing-pinch-to-zoom-images-in-wp7/

Comment: I have to put these setting before I apply scale to inner canvas or after that an also for scale less than 1 only for any scale factor.

Comment: you need to put it before applying scaling because you want to measure the change

Comment: well I applied these settings and result is that after certain scale, the inner canvas disappears totally.

Comment: actually I am not getting the logic behind the pseducode you have specified

Comment: can you please paste the whole psedo code for OnPinchDelta method